# Unreal Engine ARKit on iOS 13

Tags: ios, arkit, unreal-engine4

As you know iOS 13 just launched. I'm trying to get the basic AR template to launch on it. I am able to get it to load without error to the device.

Once the main screen loads I get nothing but a black screen and no prompt from iOS to use the camera and the AR session does not start.

I'm wondering if there is anything from this console log that could help me understand how to fix?

I current have Xcode 11 installs and I have the iOS 12SDK installed so that Unreal can use that for compiling.

```
     Install \ Update of "ARKitDemo.ipa" finished in 13.73 seconds
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]
LogPlayLevel: Took 20.579781s to run mono, ExitCode=0
LogPlayLevel: Running: mono "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.23/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/IOS/DeploymentServer.exe" Deploy -manifest "/Users/mwallace/Documents/Unreal Projects/ARKitDemo/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/Manifest_DeltaUFSFiles_00008020000102822284002E.txt" -device 00008020-000102822284002E -additionalcommandline "-SessionId=8FDCD4434C422187D9B24BA101DE940A -
SessionOwner="mwallace" -SessionName="Launch On Device" " -bundle io.sixfifteen.unreal.bridgestonear
LogPlayLevel:   [deploy] Created deployment server.
LogPlayLevel:   Running as local instance
LogPlayLevel:   [DD] Trying to connect to mobile device running iOS ...
LogPlayLevel:   [DD] Mobile Device 'Matthew's iPhone' connected
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]  ... Connected to bundle 'io.sixfifteen.unreal.bridgestonear'
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]  ... Copying '/Users/mwallace/Documents/Unreal Projects/ARKitDemo/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/cookeddata/arkitdemo/arkitdemo.uproject' -> '/Library/Caches/arkitdemo/arkitdemo.uproject' ...
LogPlayLevel:   Directory (/Library/Caches/arkitdemo) doesn't exist!
LogPlayLevel:   CreateDirectory (/Library/Caches/arkitdemo) failed
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]  ... Failed to transfer a file, extended error is 'AFCFileRefOpen (/Library/Caches/arkitdemo/arkitdemo.uproject) failed with error 12'
LogPlayLevel:   [DD]
LogPlayLevel: Took 183.998008s to run mono, ExitCode=0
LogPlayLevel: ********** DEPLOY COMMAND COMPLETED **********
LogPlayLevel: ********** RUN COMMAND STARTED **********
LogPlayLevel: Starting Client....
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Deploy Task, Time: 334.707721
LogPlayLevel: Running: /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/instruments -w '00008020-000102822284002E' -t 'Activity Monitor' -D "/Users/mwallace/Documents/Unreal Projects/ARKitDemo/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/launch.trace" 'io.sixfifteen.unreal.bridgestonear'
LogPlayLevel: Instruments Trace Complete: /Users/mwallace/Documents/Unreal Projects/ARKitDemo/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/launch.trace
LogPlayLevel: Deleting /Users/mwallace/Documents/Unreal Projects/ARKitDemo/Saved/StagedBuilds/IOS/launch.trace
LogPlayLevel: ********** RUN COMMAND COMPLETED **********
LogPlayLevel: BUILD SUCCESSFUL
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Run Task, Time: 64.566293
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Post Launch Task, Time: 0.000009
LogPlayLevel: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=0 (Success)
LogPlayLevel: Launch On Completed. Time: 441.016508
```

Comment: I see the same thing. I've tried everything that I can think of or googled and still nothing. Did you post on the unreal forums as well?

Comment: I've posted on both here and the answers unreal site. This seems like an iOS 13 bug with the engine.